# How to write an "exclusive" query in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, join

I am going over a past paper for a database course I am taking and I am stuck on an SQL question

Here is the schema provided

- Country(name, capital, area), name is the key
- People(country, population, children, adult) where country refers to the
  name in Country, population is the total population, and children and adult
  is the percentage of the children and adult population.
- Language(country,language,percentage) – for each language spoken in the
  country, it lists the percentage of the population that speaks the language.

Here is the question:

> > Write the following query in SQL: Find languages that are *only* spoken in countries whose total population exceeds 10^7.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT l.language
FROM people p, language l
WHERE l.country = p.country AND
    p.population > 10^7
```

The bit I am confused about is how to check that there are no other countries which a language is spoken in but the population is less than 10^7.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Since this is for a DB course, you should read up on proper join syntax. What you're using is older/obsolete (but still functional) notation, and I call it "lazy syntax".

Comment: "Only more than X" means "None less than or equal to X"

Comment: One gimmicky thing (which I think this question is getting at) is, for any given language, ask yourself: how many countries is it spoken in, and how many of those countries have > X population?   Or you could ask yourself: "If I had two tables, one with countries population > X, the other < X, what would be true about those tables for a language that meets the condition?"  Hope that helps without giving an answer.  I think that's the kind of thoughts this question is encouraging you to pursue, be interesting to see what other people think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all languages. From that set remove all languages spoken in countries with population <= 10^7. The reminder should be languages only spoken on countries with population > 10^7.

```
select language from languages
where language not in (
    select language from languages l
    join people p on l.country = p.country
    where p.population <= 10^7)
```

This works on the basis that your design has the restriction that every language must be spoken in at least one country ;)

Comment: This is one way, but a way that (in my limited experience) is *not* taught as the classical/academic solution because it uses a sub-select.

Comment: "This works on the basis that..." -- I don't think that is a safe assumption!

Comment: If you want a solution without a subquery, use MINUS to combine two SELECTs.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH T 
     AS
     (
      SELECT l.language, 
             p.country, p.population
        FROM people p, language l
       WHERE l.country = p.country
     )
SELECT language
  FROM T
EXCEPT
SELECT language
  FROM T
 WHERE population <= 10000000;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT language
  FROM language AS l1
 WHERE 10000000 < ( SELECT MIN(p.population)
                      FROM people p, language l
                     WHERE l.country = p.country
                           AND l.language = l1.language );
```

Similarly:

```
SELECT language
  FROM language AS l1
 WHERE 10000000 < ALL ( SELECT p.population
                          FROM people p, language l
                         WHERE l.country = p.country
                               AND l.language = l1.language );
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to get the distinct languages spoken in each size-group of countries, then LEFT JOIN those two lists and end up with the list of languages only spoken in countries with population larger than 10^7 (or 10000000).

```
;WITH Bigs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT l.language
    FROM people p
    INNER JOIN language l ON l.country = p.country
    WHERE p.population > 10000000
)
,Littles AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT l.language
    FROM people p
    INNER JOIN language l ON l.country = p.country
    WHERE p.population <= 10000000
)
SELECT b.language 
FROM Bigs b
LEFT JOIN Littles l ON l.language = b.language
WHERE l.language IS NULL
```